# How to retrieve context parameters through EL in Java EE 6?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, java-ee-6, el

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSF 2 - How can I get a context-param value from web.xml using JSF EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523193/jsf-2-how-can-i-get-a-context-param-value-from-web-xml-using-jsf-el)

I was used to retrieve context parameters using EL in this manner

```
${applicationScope.configs.parameterName}
```

And it works perfectly.

Now, I'm working a new project that uses Tomcat 7 and Java EE 6 (servlet and jsp spec) and the example above does not work. I created the web.xml just to set some parameters. Inside a servlet, I just use

```
getServletContext().getInitParameter( "parameterName" );
```

And it works fine, but when I try to use the first example in my JSPs, it does not work, nothing happens, like the "configs" map does not exists. I already searched for some solution but I didn't find anything. I tried several things too like:

```
${applicationScope.initParameter.parameterName}
${applicationScope.initParameters.parameterName}
```

And it does not work too. I would like to know how to retrieve context parameters in my JSPs using Tomcat 7 (Java EE 6).

Comment: A quick google search yields >>[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523193/jsf-2-how-can-i-get-a-context-param-value-from-web-xml-using-jsf-el)<<

Comment: I swear that i searched for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I swear that I tried to search for it, but I didn't find anything. With jahroy comment I found what I need. It was pretty easy indeed. I just need to use:

```
${initParam.parameterName}
```

I really forgot about it.

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to upvote the existing answer rather than creating a duplicate question/answer?

Comment: I don't think that is the same question. They are similar, not equal. I just answered my own question because it is a good practice and if the question remains opened, maybe it help another person with the same doubt. I just upvoted the answer of the question that you send me. Thanks.

Comment: No, don't. The existing question concerns modern JSF/Facelets. The current question concerns legacy JSP/Servlet. Whilst they have smiliarities in EL, they are definitely not the same.